# What classes are best for beating the Boss Hive?

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

The new 0.2 version of Desktop Dungeons has a new special level called the Boss Hive.  The special feature of this dungeon is that it includes all possible monster types, and all monsters (regardless of level) are given the same bonuses that the boss monster of that type gets.  This means extra damage, extra hit points, and extra special abilities.

In order to unlock the new class in the 0.2 version, you need to beat Boss Hive with 4 different classes.  So which classes are best suited to this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had easy wins with vampires and transmuters (of course, since they're pretty overpowered) and slightly less easy wins with elf bloodmages and halfling assassins (the ones which kill lower-level monsters in one hit). The success of the bloodmage depends on the glyphs found of course (and on how early you find BURNDARAYZ)

Comment: I assume by mage you mean bloodmage?

Comment: @bwarner: Whoops, yes. Although plain wizards are also pretty good.